# cakephp 3 prefix routing

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-routing

I'm trying to set up a routing prefix in cakephp 3 so any URLs starting with /json/ get the prefix key set and I can change the layout accordingly in the app controller. Other than that, they should use the usual controller and action. I have added the following to routes.php

```
$routes->prefix('json', function($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
        '/:controller/:action/*',
        [],
        ['routeClass' => 'InflectedRoute']
    );
});
```

I want to direct all requests with json as first url segment to controller specified in second url segment. e.g. /json/users/add_account_type/ goes to users controller. However when accessing this URL I get the message:

> Error: Create the class UsersController below in file:
>   src/Controller/Json/UsersController.php

whereas I want it to be using

> src/Controller/UsersController.php

I think this should be possible but I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong when consulting the book. Have partly based my code on: [CakePHP3.x controller name in url when using prefix routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25359271/cakephp3-x-controller-name-in-url-when-using-prefix-routing)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply how prefix routing now works in 3.x, as explained in the docs, prefixes are being mapped to subnamespaces, and thus to separate controllers in subfolders.

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing**

If you'd wanted to change that behavior (I don't really see why), one way would be to implement a custom `ControllerFactory` dispatcher filter.

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html**

On a side note, the `RequestHandler` component supports layout/template switching out of the box, so maybe you should give that a try.

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html**

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It looks like the RequestHandler functionality is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix routing is a way of namespacing parts of your routes to a dedicated controller. It seem that what you want is a scope and not a prefix, for what you describe:

```
Router::scope('/json', function($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('InfledtedRoute')
});
```

Comment: This worked to direct my request to the right place but in my AppController I couldn't work out how to tell what scope I was in and change layout accordingly.

Comment: The layout? Why are you not using the automatic Json views? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html